# Open Popup for one time in bigcommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this question asked several time, i have done a small research and added my code, still somewhere i am doing wrong, now for me. Below point what i need to achieve.
1. Open popup on homepage load.
2. Popup should be in center for all browsers.
3. Popup should be fade in.
4. Should open only one time for one user.

this is my test website http://popuptest.mybigcommerce.com/

So far Popup opening, For me popup in center and looks fade in working. but session not working .

Below is the code i am working

In index.html

```
  <div id="boxes">
  <div style="top: 199.5px; left: 551.5px; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window">
      <img src="images/coupon2011.jpg" width="507" height="300" /> 
    <a href="#" class="close"><img src="images/closelabel.gif" width="66" height="22" /></a>
</div>
<!-- Mask to cover the whole screen -->
<div style="width: 1478px; height: 602px; display: none; opacity: 0.8;" id="mask"></div>
</div>
```

Now in htmlhead.html, below code used.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { 

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

//if close button is clicked
$('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    //Cancel the link behavior
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
   });      

//if mask is clicked
$('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
});     

});

</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var once_per_session=1

function get_cookie(Name) {
var search = Name + "="
var returnvalue = "";
if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
offset = document.cookie.indexOf(search)
if (offset != -1) { // if cookie exists
offset += search.length
end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", offset);
if (end == -1)
end = document.cookie.length;
returnvalue=unescape(document.cookie.substring(offset, end))
 }
}
return returnvalue;
}

function loadpopunder(){
if (get_cookie('popunder')==''){
loadpopunder()
document.cookie="popunder=yes"
 }
}
function loadpopunder(){
if (once_per_session==0)
loadpopunder()
else
{
if (get_cookie('popunder')==''){
loadpopunder()
document.cookie="popunder=yes"
}
}
}
</script>
```

Any suggestion or tutorial would be great to complete.

Comment: I'd note that while you're saying "popup" and "popunder" it looks like you're just implementing a modal dialog. True popups of this nature have been blocked by major browsers' popup blockers for years now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript library [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). With this library you can easily set and get cookies.

If you use js-cookie your htmlhead.html code should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // Check if cookie exists
    if (Cookies.get('popunder')) {
        return;
    }

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    //transition effect     
    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);    
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);  

    //Get the window height and width
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    //Set the popup window to center
    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    //transition effect
    $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

    // Set cookie to be sure the popover activated again
    Cookies.set('popunder', '1');

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
   });      

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });     

});

</script>
```